# IBMDB2 OLeDB connection exception "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt"

Tags: c#, .net, exception, db2, oledbdatareader

Facing very weird issue **while running below program on platform target x64**. it is absolutely working fine on x86.

Steps to reproduce:

1. db2 server installed on the remote machine
2. db2 client installed on the local machine
3. now run this program (only after changing platform target AnyCpu to x64).
   then issue occurs at ***OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader();***

**STRANGE BEHAVIOUR: with x86 platform. this program is working fine.**

P.S.: I have verified this program. it is working with all server like SQL,MySQL,Oracle etc. issue only with the **IBMDB2 server**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace OledbAndOdbc
{
 public class Program
{
    static string odbcstr = "Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};Database=xxxx;Hostname=xxxx;Port=50000;Protocol=TCPIP;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxx;";
    static string oledbStr = "Provider=IBMDADB2;Database=xxxx;Hostname=xxxx;Protocol=TCPIP;Port=50000;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxx;";

    static string strSQLODBC = "select  * from CUSTOMERS ;";
    static string strOLedb = "select * from CUSTOMERS ;";
    public static void ConnectionCallback(object callback)
    {
        int[] array = callback as int[];
        if (0 == Convert.ToInt32(array[1])) // ODBC connection
        {
            System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection odbcConnection = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(odbcstr);
            odbcConnection.Open();
            System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand ODBCCommand = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand(strSQLODBC, odbcConnection);
            ODBCCommand.CommandTimeout = 120;
            System.Data.Common.DbDataReader dataReader = ODBCCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
               // Todo
            }
        }
        if (1 == Convert.ToInt32(array[0])) // OLeDB connection
        {
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection oleDbConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(oledbStr);
            oleDbConnection.Open();
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand OleDbCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(strOLedb, oleDbConnection);
            OleDbCommand.CommandTimeout = 120;
            System.Data.Common.DbDataReader dataReader = OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
               //to do
            }
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Program.ConnectionCallback, new int[] { 1, 0 });
        }
        Thread.CurrentThread.Join();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: EDIT your question to *specify* which exact version of a Db2-client that you are using and who is the supplier? (MS, or IBM) etc.

Comment: I am using IBM DB2 client 11.1 x64bit. I am facing this issue only when I change platform target to x64 from visual studio 2015. However, it works perfectly fine with visual studio target platform x86.

Comment: Which editions of Windows x64 does it fail on?  Which 32-bit editions does it work on?

Comment: I am running this program through visual studio 2015 on machine windows 2k12 R2 64 bit. the issue occurs only when I change my program platform target to x64. via right click->program->Properties->platform target. it works with "AnyCpu" and "x86" but not with "x64"

Comment: Have you debugged to find which line of code causes the exception?

Comment: yes, the line of code from above which is causing an issue.     System.Data.Common.DbDataReader dataReader = OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader();  And very weird thing is, why the same code is working with x86, not with x64